# K8S PersistentVolume of nfs type - what does "server" field mean?

Tags: kubernetes

Here is the example of the PersistentVolume of nfs type spec:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0003
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: slow
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: /tmp
    server: 172.17.0.2
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

In some guides `server` field in `nfs` section is just an IP or hostname to the actual NFS server, but in LFS258 guide `server` field is set to the node name of k8s `node` object itself and it seems to work too.

How is it resolved in the last case? Any reason it is not explicitly mentioned in spec that it can be set to Node name?

```
nfs.server (string), required

server is the hostname or IP address of the NFS server. More info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes#nfs
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/